# Append dataframes in a loop from files located in different directories?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create one pandas dataframe from files which are in different directories. In this directories are also other files and I want to read only .parquet files.

I created a function but it returns nothing:

```
def all_files(root, extensions):
  files = pd.DataFrame()
  for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(root):
    for file in file_names: 
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in extensions:
            data = pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(dir_path, file))
            files.append(data)
            
  return files
```

Im calling this functions like this:

`one_file = all_files(".", [".parquet"])`

While Im replacing `return files` for `return data` it returns correctly one from the files so the issue may lay in line `files.append(data)`. I would be happy with any advice.

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) does not work in place, it is *returning a new object* (unlike `append` method of built-in python `list`), try replacing

```
files.append(data)
```

using

```
files = files.append(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

A typical strategy is to load all dataframes into a list, then `pc.concat()` them at the end. This avoids the repeated allocation of a progressively larger dataframe, and it also allows concurrent load. If you wish, it also allows you to add an identifying `key` of your choice for each `DataFrame` concatenated:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def read_all_parquet(root, extensions, sort_files=False, with_keys=False):
    file_list = [
        os.path.join(dir_path, file)
        for dir_path, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(root)
        for file in file_names
        if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in extensions
    ]
    if sort_files:
        file_list = sorted(file_list)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as ex:
        frame_list = list(ex.map(pd.read_parquet, file_list))
    df = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=0, keys=file_list if with_keys else None)
    return df
```

**Example/Test**

```py
for a in ['foo', 'bar', 'fubar']:
    d = os.path.join('test', a)
    os.makedirs(d)
    for i in range(100):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(3, 4)*i, columns=list('abcd'))
        df.to_parquet(os.path.join(d, f'file-{i:06d}.parquet'))

#---
%%time
df = read_all_parquet('test', '.parquet', sort_files=True, with_keys=True)
# Wall time: 537 ms
```

The `sort_files` argument can be used to sort the files (`os.walk` is unordered) and `with_keys` adds an index with the filename, if desired.

```py
>>> df
                                     a     b     c    d
test/bar/file-000000.parquet   0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
                               1   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
                               2   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
test/bar/file-000001.parquet   0   1.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
                               1   0.0   1.0   0.0  0.0
...                                ...   ...   ...  ...
test/fubar/file-000098.parquet 1   0.0  98.0   0.0  0.0
                               2   0.0   0.0  98.0  0.0
test/fubar/file-000099.parquet 0  99.0   0.0   0.0  0.0
                               1   0.0  99.0   0.0  0.0
                               2   0.0   0.0  99.0  0.0
```